# How to find existing folder name in sqlite iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I created a table with few field as UNIQUE. So, I have to show an alert to user while they insert the duplicate foldername into table. Can anyone tell me "How to check for an existing data before it can be inserted into the table in sqlite database"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check for record by following code

```
-(BOOL)CheckForRecord:(NSString *)Name
{
    BOOL isRecordPresent=false;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"SELECT ID FROM TBL_Name WHERE Column_Name=\"%@\"",Name];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                isRecordPresent = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                isRecordPresent = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    if(sqlite3_close(database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to close database on memwarning with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }   
    return isRecordPresent;
}
```

Comment: dude i had a small doubt.when the name already in the table i want to show alert like this .how ??

Comment: "UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Folders must have a unique name." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [errorAlert show];"

Comment: yes you can do that, like this 
if!([self CheckForRecord:name])
{
//pur alertview here
}

Comment: hmm ya sure...its well.